# How are files linked in a windows forms application project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm at a loss for how files are compiled together, seemingly without referencing each other.  I just started Visual Studio 2012 and I started a new project and then clicked Windows Forms Application.  The solution includes the following files: Form1.Designer.cs, AssemblyInfo.cs, Settings.Designer.cs, and Resources.resx as far as I can tell.  That would be four files that are all executed but seemingly without any references to each other.  Does C# just execute all of the files in the same directory as the one including Main()?  If so, then how does it determine the order?  I cannot find this information elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure about most of this, but `AssemblyInfo.cs` is "special" in that it only contains assembly-level attributes. However, I'm certain that .NET does not in fact execute source files. It runs `Main()` and only does what that method tells it to. Now, what does happen is that all the files in the project are compiled in one go and joined in a single assembly.

Comment: Perhaps this tutorial might help you understand .net projects http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s1p1.html

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What makes you think the form designer has anything to do with anything?

Comment: John Saunders, just post it as one comment.  To answer your question, I was trying to use the form designer as an example of what I was asking the question for.  It's terribly worded so I'll change it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the raw contents of the project file (open it with an external editor) you will see that it is not arbitrary. The project "relates those files together". It will be in the same folder as the other files named project_name.csproj (for C#)

For a closer study of how compilation works in .NET I would suggest trying the command line compilers. csc for C# and vbc for VB.

The format is XML and the begining will look something like this: (Even a trivially small application will have a sizeable prj file.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{37482A08-A668-45C7-A650-37EA2248B1F6}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>

    etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

there is also a file called `Program.cs` it has a main method, this method determines what the application should run first, and it has a default to run `Form1.cs` see the line:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

so now you know which class is going to be compiled first, then you link your first compiled form with another form or anything else and launch it using an action event handler like button click for example.

Comment: `Program.cs` is not a class - it's a file.

Comment: The fact that Program.cs is a series of bytes on disk makes it a file. It may _contain_ a class declaration, but it is a file.

Comment: What are you talking about? The the thing with the file type _is_ the file. The file is not the same thing as the text in the file. The text in the file has a meaning when interpreted by the compiler. In this case, that meaning is a class named "Program" that has a method named "Main".

Comment: And before you decide I'm simply being pedantic, consider partial classes, where parts of a single class may be distributed across several files. It's also possible to have a single file containing many classes.

Comment: @Myself Mouth.Open(); Mouth.Insert(Foot.getInstance());